# how to copy directory structure without actually copying the content into another directory

Tags: java, directory

I want to copy the directory structure without copying the content/files. I want to copy only folder structure.
I have written a sample program but it is also copying the content/files also.

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.nio.channels.*;

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public class CopyDirectory{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        CopyDirectory cd = new CopyDirectory();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String source = "C:\\abcd\\Documents\\1";
        File src = new File(source);        
        String destination = "C:\\abcd\\Documents\\2";
        File dst = new File(destination);
        cd.copyDirectory(src, dst);
        }

    public void copyDirectory(File srcPath, File dstPath) throws IOException{
        if (srcPath.isDirectory())
        {
            if (!dstPath.exists())
            {
                dstPath.mkdir();
            }

            String files[] = srcPath.list();
            for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("\n"+files[i]);
                copyDirectory(new File(srcPath, files[i]), new File(dstPath, files[i]));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Directory copied.");
    }
   }
```

I am struck at this point.
Thank you.

Comment: See that little part where you copy all the files?  Yeah, just erm...  Get rid of that?

Comment: Why don't you just delete the part of the code that writes the file and replace it with dstPath.createNewFile()? You will just end up with a bunch of empty files, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: I do not believe you when you say YOU have written a small program. Otherwise, you would have noticed you also wrote code to copy the files...

Comment: @Corbin, i have understood the mistake and overcome the isue and edited in that question. Its working fine.Thank you.

Comment: Um is it ok for the op to edit the question by removing the code that was causing the problem? now it looks like the question doesn't make sense with the current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import java.io.File;

public class StartCloneFolderOnly {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        cloneFolder("C:/source",
                "C:/target");       
    }

    public static void cloneFolder(String source, String target) {
        File targetFile = new File(target);
        if (!targetFile.exists()) {
            targetFile.mkdir();
        }
        for (File f : new File(source).listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
                String append = "/" + f.getName();
                System.out.println("Creating '" + target + append + "': "
                        + new File(target + append).mkdir());
                cloneFolder(source + append, target + append);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm right, you just want to copy the folders.

**1.)** Copy directory with sub-directories and files 
**2.)** Place ***1.*** wherever
**3a.)** Instantiate to list files in parent directory into an arrayList
**3b.)** Instantiate to list the new subfolders into an arrayList
**3c.)** Instantiate to list all files in each subfolder into their own arrayLists
**4.)** Use a for-loop to now delete every file within the new directory and subfolder

From this, you should have a copy of the new directory with all files removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.nio.channels.*;

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    public class CopyDirectory{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    CopyDirectory cd = new CopyDirectory();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String source = "C:\\abcd\\Documents\\1";
    File src = new File(source);        
    String destination = "C:\\abcd\\Documents\\2";
    File dst = new File(destination);
    cd.copyDirectory(src, dst);
    }

public void copyDirectory(File srcPath, File dstPath) throws IOException{
    if (srcPath.isDirectory())
    {
        if (!dstPath.exists())
        {
            dstPath.mkdir();
        }

        String files[] = srcPath.list();

        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("\n"+files[i]);
            copyDirectory(new File(srcPath, files[i]), new File(dstPath, files[i]));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Directory copied.");
}
```

}